# The whole staff vs all the staff

Tags: differences

Is there any difference in the use of "the whole staff" and "all the staff"? Are they pretty much synonymous like all day/the whole day or not? In a corpus I have found several examples of "On behalf of all the staff," but none with "on behalf of the whole staff" and I wonder why that may be.

Comment: 'All the staff' stresses individuals and thus connotes more intimacy. It doesn't sound wonderful with formal (singular) agreement ('All the staff wishes you well').

Comment: There's little real difference between the two. Just two different ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: As indicated by [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+whole+staff+went%2Call+the+staff+went&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) (if you toggle between *American* and *British* corpuses), explicitly singular ***the whole staff*** was never used much in BrE - and in the past couple of decades, even AmE has finally moved decisively in favour of ***all the staff*** (which I assume everyone on both sides of the pond would treat as syntactically plural).

Comment: I don't think verb agreement is an issue here.